# Converting a list of datetime string in to a datetime object for Matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I have this:

```
from datetime import datetime
A=[“datetime(2020,9,20)”, “datetime(2020,9,21)”, “datetime(2020,9,22)”.....]
```

But I want

```
BA=[datetime(2020,9,20), datetime(2020,9,21), datetime(2020,9,22).....]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have a multiple lines like these in the file?  Are there other lines of different text in between?  Can you just find `[“”]` and replace with nothing and then find `^(A=.*)$` and replace with `B$1`.  Just two steps.

Comment: @Jiho Dude -What output do you hope to get?